# title service doesn't work in SSR when the module is lazy loaded

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-universal

when you load a module normally, title service works fine in SSR, and the source code updated with the new title

```
// example.module.ts
let routes = [
  { path: '**', component:  ExampleComponent }
]
```

```
// example.component.ts
if(this.platform.isPlatformServer()){
  this.titleService.setTitle('example');
}
```

but when the module is lazy loaded, title and meta services don't work in SSR (only works in client-rendering)

```
// app.module
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./example.module').then(
        (modules) => modules.ExampleModule
      ),
  },
```

`ExampleComponent` is rendered in the server as expected, (tested by logging `this.platform.platformId` to the console)
but title and meta services only works when the condition `if(this.platform.isPlatformServer()` is removed.

I set this condition to test the behavior of title and meta services in server side. also Angular doesn't insert the added meta tags and the new title in the source code if rendered in client-side which makes issue with SEO and when scratching meta tags from the app or sharing to social media platform, that's why updating title and meta tags doesn't matter to me in client-side rendering.

also, it seems that if the module is lazy-loaded `fileReplacements` doesn't work, so `environment` has different values in the server and the browser
`console.log({ environment })` gives different values in the server's console that the browser's console if you build the app in development mode.

it seems that `ngOnChanges` doesn't fire on the server when the module loaded lazily
[minimal repro](https://github.com/eng-dibo/issue-meta-tags/blob/main/src/app/feature/lazy-child.component.ts#L13)

run `npm start`

in `feature/lazy-child.component.ts` the title should be set when a change is detected,but it don't.

also `console.log({ changes })` appears in the browser's console, but doesn't appear in the server's console

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.6
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.4
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.2.6
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.6
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.0.2
@schematics/angular             13.2.6
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript
```

Comment: it seems that `ngOnChanges` doesn't fire on the server when the module loaded lazily
[minimal repro](https://github.com/eng-dibo/issue-meta-tags/blob/main/src/app/feature/lazy-child.component.ts#L13)

run `npm start`

in `feature/lazy-child.component.ts` the title should be set when a change is detected,but it don't.

also `console.log({ changes })` appears in the browser's console, but doesn't appear in the server's console

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in our application, so we just moved logic about setting title and metatags to `canActivate` guard.

It's obvious and simple solution

```
 {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule),
    canActivate: [setMetaTags],
    data: {
      title: 'Main title',
    }
  },


export class SetMetaTags implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private titleService: Title
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const value = route.data?.title || 'Default title';
    
    this.titleService.setTitle(value);

    return true;
  }

}
```

less obvious, you should follow this guide https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/angular-seo-guide-universal-server-side-rendering-lazy-alapati/

The main idea is that, you should pass SSR map of lazy load modules, so it knows what modules do you have:

> app.server.module.ts should have ModuleMapLoaderModule imported from @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader in order to work lazyloading modules view source content.

Comment: I get meta tags from database, after loading the data itself, so I need to implement it from inside the component after it fully loaded